# Spring-Boot and scala cannot find main class

Tags: spring, scala, maven

I am trying to make a simple hello world web application in Scala which bootstraps spring-boot as its framework using maven as build tool.

I looked around a bit (there are a few tutorials with Gradle and much less information with maven, is there a reason for it?)

I Managed to get everything wired up but now i am stuck with this error when trying to run the application:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SampleWebApplication
```

Here is the source code,

[parent pom from github](https://github.com/jleskovar/spring-boot-scala-app-parent/blob/master/pom.xml) removing some code about git and deployment leaving the structure intact

Then my web application pom:

> ```
> <parent>
>     <groupId>X.Y.Z</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-scala-app-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
> </parent>
> <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> <build>
> <plugins>
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
>     <configuration>
>         <mainClass>SampleWebApplication</mainClass>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>repackage</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> </plugins>
> ```

SampleWebApplication:

> ```
> import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
> class SampleWebApplication extends App {
>   SpringApplication.run(classOf[SampleConfig]);
> }
> ```

SampleConfig:

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @ComponentScan
> class SampleConfig {
> }
> ```

Comment: You don't have your `SampleWebApplication` in any package? Are you sure that you have it at the root?

Comment: yes i am its in the root of the project. src/main/scala

Comment: Put your class `SampleWebApplication` in a package, not in the default (unnamed) package, and then specify the fully-qualified name in the pom. For example `com.myproject.SampleWebApplication`.

Comment: Are you also including the Scala library in your project? If you try to run this as a Java application without the Scala library, the JVM won't be able to find the standard Scala classes such as `App` and it won't be able to load your class `SampleWebApplication`.

Comment: Scala library is included and i tried putting the SampleWebApplication in a package it didnt work, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add it inside your build tag

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <scalaVersion>2.11.5</scalaVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```